# Select columnName from another field

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm a newbie in MS Access.

Table A:

```
No          Date(dd/mm/yyyy)
12345       1/5/2015
23446       1/7/2015
```

Table B:

```
No        Month1    Month2   Month3
12345     10        9        7
23446     8         5        3
```

I have 2 tables, A and B.

I want combine two tables, that the columns from table B are No and one of monthX column that based on calculation of current month minus month from column date in table A.

Today is 1/7/2015
So 12345 is month 3 and 23446 is month1

The combination table that i hope is:

```
No         BMonth
12345      7 (use month3)
23446      8 (use month1)
```

How can I code to get that result?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you might want to reconsider your table B structure. Maybe No,Month,Date or Month Number. The just use a WHERE statement to indicate which month number based off that field. :  SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE No = 12345 AND MonthNumber = 3

Comment: I agree with Gene that the datamodel looks strange. Is the column No primary key for both tables?

Comment: @gene : thx for answering! so the data will mutiply 3 times? Is that become so many rows? Can we do something like, if i want month3, i created column of the calculation ex: A=3,  so it become select month+A from tableB ?

Comment: @throsten : yes throsten. I didnt create specific primary key for both tables

Comment: If you alter your structure you would just need to display all rows where your 'No' are equal and where monthNo equals the month you're searching for. I'm not sure if you can do month+A in a query, but I know you can if you create a dynamic query in VBA